# Cant navigate when using Jquery in MVC3

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, hide, show

Hei all,

I am trying to show / hide my login screen when user clicks the login link (div id ="_login") which is in the _Layout.cshtml. 
My logIn screen is also inside a div (id ="_logInScreen") in the _Layout.cshtml.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
               $('#_logInScreen').hide();
               $('#_login').click(function () {                  
                  $('#_logInScreen').show(400);
                    return false;
               });
               $('#_closeLogIn').click(function () {
                   $('#_logInScreen').hide(500);
                   return false;
               });
               $('body').click(function () {
                   $('#_logInScreen').hide(500);
                   return false;
               });
               $('#_logInScreen').click(function () {                   
                   $('#_logInScreen').show();
                   return false;
               });
           });
```

It works fine.

But while doing so, I cant navigate my menu link which uses

```
@Html.ActionLink("Home","Index", "Home")

@Html.ActionLink("Help","Index", "Help")
```

any help?

Comment: The links that are not working may also have their events disabled by your code. You have a body click function there and it could be the culprit

Comment: No problem man - try and make sure the selectors are specific, if they are too global you can run into problems like this. :) please provide a flag up :)

Answer (score 0):

```
           $('body').click(function () {
               $('#_logInScreen').hide(500);
               return false;
           });
```

remove the `return false;` line.